# TypeError: string indices must be integers! what should i do

Tags: python, typeerror

```
import sys
a = int(sys.argv[1])
def count_holes(n):
    dic = {'1':0, '2':0, '3':0, '4':1, '5':0, '6':1, '7':0, '8':2, '9':1}
    l = str(n)
    counter = 0
    i = 1

    for i in l:
        while i != len(l):
            counter = counter + dic[l[i]]
    print(counter)
count_holes(a)
```

i got this:
 counter = counter + dic[l[i]]
TypeError: string indices must be integers

Comment: what are you doing? what you want?

Comment: That `while` loop is infinite, if it works at all.

Comment: it should count how many holes in number

Comment: `l` is a string. `for i in l` means `i` will be a string. So `while i!=len(l)` is always true, and `l[i]` is trying to use a string `i` as the index of another string `l`

Comment: Maybe you need integers as indices? Something like `dic={1:0, 2:0, 4:0...` ?

Comment: what should i do?

Comment: Maybe; Look at the Python variable type. `'1'` is string and `1` is a inteager vs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're making this too complicated. You're getting that `TypeError` because you are trying to use the characters of `l` to index `l`. But you don't need to index into `l`, just directly iterate over the chars in the number string.

Here's a repaired version of your code.

```
import sys

def count_holes(n):
    dic = {'1':0, '2':0, '3':0, '4':1, '5':0, '6':1, '7':0, '8':2, '9':1}
    counter = 0
    for c in str(n):
        counter += dic[c]
    return counter

a = int(sys.argv[1])
print(count_holes(a))
```

---

Here's some test code:

```
for i in (12357, 4, 66, 8, 999):
    print(i, count_holes(i))
```

and its output

```
12357 0
4 1
66 2
8 2
999 3
```

Comment: Good answer. And now you can see that the whole function body could be rewritten as: `return sum({'0':0, '4':1, '6':1, '8':2, '9':1}.get(c, 0) for c in str(n))`.

Comment: @Matthias Sure (although your dict should have '0':1), but I get the feeling this is homework, and that the OP is supposed to be practicing loops, so I didn't want to condense the code _too_ much.

Comment: That's why I said "Good answer". Your answer is the perfect explanation how the code should be if we want to keep the OPs structure. I just couldn't resist to add my solution (and adding the handling of the number zero btw).

Answer (score 0):

When you say i in l, i cycles through characters in the string l.  So i is a string and can't be used as an index.  You could enumerate() the string and use a second variable in the loop as your index.

If n somehow contains len(n) in it I could see how the while loop might exit but I'm not sure if that's what you are going for. Although i and len(l) are different types, so you have that going for you... Which is nice.